# License information could not be obtained from Elasticsearch for the [data] cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7

I have installed elasticsearch 7.5.1 and the same version of Kibana. My es cluster seems fine, but Kibana is not able to connect to the elasticsearch.

Kiabana.yml is as below:

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "<IP of the kibana instance>"
server.name: "<Name of the kibana instance>"
elasticsearch.hosts: [ "https://<IP of ES instance 1>:443" , "https://<IP of ES instance 2>:443" ]
elasticsearch.username: "<kibana_user>"
elasticsearch.password: "<kibana_user_password>"
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.certificate:
server.ssl.key:
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.reporting.kibanaServer.port: 443
xpack.reporting.kibanaServer.protocol: https
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "" ]
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: certificate
logging.dest: /etc/kibana/log/kibana.log
```

I have tried both kibana_oss and the non_oss, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This can be happen if ES cluster master node has not set correctly.

Test ES cluster health first

```
curl <ES_IP:PORT>/_cluster/health?pretty
```

Comment: it's green in my case @Wasantha